# Retrieve Value from MongoDB in Meteor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

So this is how my database looks right now:

```
{
_id": "r8uoPSvJY36nHgCK9",
"name": "Running",
"category": "leisure",
"duration": "2",
"createdAt": "2/10 16:42:17",
"skills": {
    "creativity": 6,
    "analytics": 3,
    "fitness": 7,
    "research": 4,
    "communication": 4,
    "problemSolving": 3,
    "timeManagement": 7,
    "leadership": 3,
    "selfMotivation": 3,
    "teamwork": 4
    },
"started": "false",
"finished": "false"
}
```

How can I query the collection so that I get the value of the creativity field and store it in a variable? I have tried something like:

```
tasks.find({'skills.creativity': this._id});
```

but it doesn't appear to work.

Comment: Could you elaborate this "it doesn't appear to work"?

Comment: It doesn't return the value of the field but a cursor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.find()` returns a *cursor* - i.e. all the matching records, not just the key that you're looking for.

If you're looking for the creativity field for a single record *and* assuming you are trying to find the document by its `_id` and not by the value of the `skills.creativity` field (which as @Styx points out would be silly) then:

```
const creativity = tasks.findOne(this._id).skills.creativity;
```

If you're looking to get the creativity field for all the matching records then:

```
const creativityArray = tasks.find(query).map((e) => e.skills.creativity);
```

where `query` defines the set of documents you're looking for.

Comment: You know, for your first example it could be just `const creativity = this._id;` :)

Comment: Oh duh. I'm going to bet he is looking for the doc with that `_id`.

Comment: Most probably :)

Comment: const creativity = tasks.findOne(this._id).skills.creativity; This is what I was looking for and it works, thank you ! @MichelFloyd